# Magento multiple level menu

Tags: php, magento, menubar

In my Magento website, I need to display Main categories and sub categories on a multilevel menu. The sub categories will change according to the main category selected.I need it as  shown in the link given below. http://www.bhphotovideo.com/ .

Comment: I mostly prefer doing it using plugins .. megamenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in navigation.php append all main categories and its child categories to jquery tabs

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too much off the goals of SO, and I'm afraid it will get closed by someone with enough reputaion.
Just to give you a starting point, it can be achieved by CSS, as making current menu item of class active and then forcing its child elements to display because of that active class in parent. Try this, you'll surely get what you want.
Cheers.

Comment: I think he is asking about building a Magento multilevel menu extension.All the menu items must be dynamic and editable from admin backend.

Comment: @Arunu, According to the link above, navigation feature like that can be achieved by just CSS. It will be multilevel for current menu item, and surely be dynamic and editable from backend, without any "extension".

Comment: yes exactly iam planning to display the main categories inside a div above the main menu and when clicked on each main category its corosponding sub category to be shown in the main menu,for this iam editing navigation.php in magento

Comment: @user2830891, I don't think, it'd be a good idea to edit navigation.php, I'm still in favour of CSS approach, but in the end, it's your choice, goodluck.